# One line of output at a time

Tags: powershell, output-buffering, powershell-ise, powershell-4.0

I want to get one line of output at a time while running this command.

`Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/rss.aspx | Format-Table -Property Title, pubDate`

So I want to get one line of output and then press `Enter` or `Any key` to get the next line of out or press `Ctrl+C` to break the command.

I couldn't achieve it with `$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'ld do something like this:

```
 $A = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/rss.aspx | select -Property Title, pubDate
FOR ( $I = 0; $I -le $A.Length; $I++ )
{
    $A[$i] 
    .\pause ""
}
```

or one liner ( look comment )

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/rss.aspx |
       select -Property Title, pubDate | 
           % { $_ ; .\pause }
```

My pause.ps1* file script:

```
param([string]$Message="Press any key to continue...")
Write-Host -NoNewLine $Message
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
Write-Host ""
```

*this doesn't work in ISE.

Comment: This can be reduced to `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/rss.aspx | Format-Table -Property Title, pubDate | foreach { ... }`

Comment: @AyanMullick There isn't any equivalent in the ISE. The best you can do is spawn a messagebox with an OK button. See [here](http://adamstech.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/how-to-properly-pause-a-powershell-script/).